# How to open bootstrap dialogue where the user click on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

When user clicks on the page I am trying to set the bootstrap dialogue modal (dialogue of 250 width) at the clicked position on mousedown event! However my dialogue modal doesn't open at the clicked position! I am trying as below so any help would be appreciated!

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
  $("#myModal").css({ "left" : x, "top" : y}); 
  $("#myModal").show();
  //I also tried
  //$("#myModal").show({ top : y, left : x });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Check at http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: Thanks! The modal opens up fine for me, but not where I click!

Comment: You have to modify the CSS of the item with class modal-dialog to change the position